# Appium : Best way to automate e-Signature scenario using Appium?

Tags: c#, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

**How to Automate e-Signature?**

I am trying to automate e-Signature scenario for iOS and android application. Anyone implemented same using Appium?

Workaround :
I tried to automate e-Signature using just tap on screen which is creating dot(.) on signature pad. This is working but want to give a try for minimal signature for real user experience.

If anyone might have solved this issue? Please suggest a workaround.

**My ENV :**

- OS : Windows 10 (64 bit)
- Mobile OS : Android
- Emulator : Android R

Answer (score 2):

Try using [testRigor](https://testrigor.com). It is as easy as:

```
drag from "signaturePad" with offset "0,0" to "signaturePad" with offset "100,100"
tap "Done"
```

Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of testRigor.

Comment: For time being I have click on screen. Dot created is working for me. I will give a try your suggestion. Thanks